# CSS external stylesheet not working when bootstrap included

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

My external stylesheet is not being compiled if I include bootstrap. But it is working in internal and inline stylesheet. Why does this thing not working with external stylesheet. And sometimes I change the browser to firefox and it works fine. What is the main problem occuring here? I want to know about the core of the problem. Please help me out in this.

Comment: What things have you tried? Any examples? You need to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your styles link is below the bootstrap CDN. When Bootstrap styles are below other styles, Bootstrap classes and styles can overtake other custom styles.

Also, every time you make changes to your styles add `?v=n` where `n` is a changing number. It's a way for the browser to know that changes have been done and by consecuence it reloads it.

e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css?v=3">`